# Core Data fetching is slow

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am retrieving a series of objects from a large database. There are between 1-20 results for each lookup. Using a fetch request as following:

```
NSPredicate *indexPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"index == %@",indexNumber];
```

I can get results back in a relatively short period of time.

```
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0623s for 9 rows.
```

However when merging all predicates with [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates: to do the fetch in one operation the speed drops.

```
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.3890s for 195 rows.
```

I have tried indexing,setting fetch and batch limits, but am unable to reduce the total fetch time. I have also tried to execute the fetch requests at the same time one by one using GDC but am having trouble setting it up. How can I reduce the time to fetch this data?

Comment: Perhaps try another database? Core Data is known to have performance bottlenecks. You could drop to SQLite... or try out Realm which is even faster - I've been meaning to test that one out.

Comment: As stated, this question does not provide enough information to get useful feedback.  What, exactly, does your "slow" fetch request look like?  What is the format of the data being searched?  What is the database schema?  What fields have indexes?  More than likely, you are simply performing a linear search over all elements, possibly applying a slow, complex predicate.

Comment: Is this compound predicate simply an "or" of 1-20 predicates like `indexPredicate` but with different index numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining 20 index lookups with `OR` is a lot of comparison in the fetch. You can improve matters by collecting the index values into an array and then using a single comparison with `IN`. Something like

```
NSArray *indexesToFetch = // A bunch of NSNumbers with index numbers of interest
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"indexNumber in %@", indexesToFetch];
```

If you have a lot of data to search through, this is still a lot of work. But using `IN` for something like this will generally be much faster than using a whole bunch of `OR`s.